# OnClick para exibir resultado

Tags: php, jquery

Peguei um código que quando é digitado algo no input, ele carrega os dados sem refresh na página, só que queria fazer isto através de botão, assim evitando bugs.

Não estou conseguindo converter o código para executar com botão.

Meu código .js:

```
$("#busca").keyup(function(){
    var campo = $("#busca").val();
    $.post('processa.php', {campo: campo},function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
    });
});
```

processa.php

```
$campo = $_POST['campo'];

$result = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome = '$campo'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

if($resultado->num_rows != 0 ){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo $row('nome');
    echo $row(senha);
    echo $row(data_nasc);
} else { 
    "Nenhum usuário encontrado" 
   }
```

form:

```
<form action="processa.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="busca" placeholder="Nome">
      <button id="executar" type="button" class="btn btn-warning"">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só mudar de `keyup` para `click`

> Descrição: vincule um manipulador de eventos ao evento
>   JavaScript "click" ou acione esse evento em um elemento. 
>   Esse método é um atalho `.on("click", handler)` nas duas primeiras variações e 
>    `.trigger("click")` na terceira. O evento click é enviado para um elemento quando o ponteiro do mouse está sobre o elemento e o botão do mouse é pressionado e liberado. Qualquer elemento `HTML` pode receber este evento.
>
> Fonte:  https://api.jquery.com/click/

```js
$("#executar").click(function() {
  var campo = $("#busca").val();
  $("#result").html(campo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="busca" type="text" />
<button id="executar" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Buscar</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui cara, muito obrigado!!!!! 2min pra poder aceitar...

Comment: @AntônioLeite Eu que agradeço em poder ajuda-ló. Att.

Answer (score 1):

O seguinte código deve resolver:

```
$("body").on('click', '#executar', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const campo = $("#busca").val();

    $.post('processa.php', {campo: campo}, function(data) {
       $("#result").html(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: Qual erro aconteceu? Talvez não seja um problema com o método em si. Você chegou a limpar o cache depois de alterar (ctrl + f5), algumas vezes isso pode atrapalhar.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar algo assim: $("#idBotao").onclick(restante da função), acredito que só essa troca será suficiente.

Comment: Testei isso agora pouco, e não funciona

Comment: $('seletor').on('click', function(){});

$('seletor').click(function (){});

Já tentou algum desses 2 ?